# Recurly .Net API, Error creating subscription

Tags: recurly

We keep getting error creating a new subscription on recurly using .NET API.
Below is our VB.Net Code

```
Dim objSub As New Subscription(acct, plan, "USD", "")
objSub.Create()
```

This is the error we get.

> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
>      at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>      at Recurly.Client.PerformRequest(HttpRequestMethod method, String urlPath, WriteXmlDelegate writeXmlDelegate, ReadXmlDelegate readXmlDelegate, ReadXmlListDelegate readXmlListDelegate)
>      at Recurly.Client.PerformRequest(HttpRequestMethod method, String urlPath, WriteXmlDelegate writeXmlDelegate, ReadXmlDelegate readXmlDelegate)
>      at Recurly.Subscription.Create()
>      at CloudLaw.Module.Recurly.Main.SubscribeUser()

The code above is perfectly working on our dev site but not on production.  Our production site is on HTTPS.

Needs some help.
Thanks

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution? I'm getting something similar accessing their API. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30819776/create-recurly-subscription-in-parse-cloud-code-via-recurly-api

Comment: In our case it has to do with duplicate subscription on same plan.